# Actual canvas text dimensions

Tags: css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Regarding HTML5 Canvas, does anyone know if it’s possible to measure the size of the actual text shown on the canvas? Using my example image, if I have ‘ac’ the size should be different than ‘acME’.

Basically I’m trying to be able to convert the actual text to inches so a customer will know how tall and wide the sticker will be (converted into inches). Much like how this site is doing it - http://fridayharborsigns.com/boatstypeface2.php

context.measeureText doesn’t have a height, and doesn’t seem to change the width if you bold the text.

[image: acME image]

-- EDIT --
Adding a jsFiddle for the canvas element.
https://jsfiddle.net/cv2egkwn/18/

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const heightwidth = document.getElementById('heightwidth');

const fontSize = 100;

context.font = `${fontSize}px Arial`;
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.textAlign = "center";
context.textBaseline = "middle";
context.fillText('acME', 200, 100);

const width = context.measureText('acME').width;
heightwidth.innerHTML = `Width: ${width} <br> Height: ${fontSize}`;
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide a working demo for us? Thanks

Comment: @sol here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cv2egkwn/18/